# Filter on datetime not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have read access to a database which has two fields as below:

```
Date1                    Place
2019-03-01 15:56:04.000  P1
2019-03-01 16:30:40.000  P2 
2018-06-21 13:30:40.000  P1  And so on
```

I am running a query as below:

```
select * from db where Date1='2019-03-01'
```

But I get below output

```
Date1  Place
```

I don't get the two rows.

Expected output

```
    Date1                    Place
    2019-03-01 15:56:04.000  P1
    2019-03-01 16:30:40.000  P2
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Well `2019-03-01 15:56:04.000` is not `2019-03-01` (which is implicitly midnight, if extended to a time). What's the type of the `Date1` column? If an ISO 8601 string then `LIKE` will help, if a `DATETIME` then `DATE` can help (or a range).

Comment: What do you get if you say `where date between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-02' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is because `2019-03-01 16:30:40.000` and `2019-03-01` *aren't* the same value. `2019-03-01` is effectively `2019-03-01 00:00:00`.

Instead use date boundaries:

```sql
SELECT Date1,
       Place
FROM dbo.db --Do you really have a table called db?
WHERE Date1 >= '20190301'
  AND Date1 < '20190302';
```

I also use the format `yyyyMMdd`. `yyyy-MM-dd` *can* be an ambiguous format; specifically if you are using the older data and time data types (`datetime` and `smalldatetime`) where unless you are using the (American) `ENGLISH` language it's likely that a value of `2019-03-01`   will be read in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`. As such, it's best to use either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` when dealing with literal strings for date (and time) values, as it will always be read correctly, regardless of the language and data type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the time component on the column.

You can use a range:

```
select *
from db
where Date1 >= '2019-03-01' and
      Date1 < '2019-03-02'
```

Or convert the column to a date:

```
where conert(date, Date1) = '2019-03-01'
```

Comment: *"Or convert the column to a date:"* Don't do this. [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734)

Comment: I also *assume* you mean `Date1 < '2019-03-02'` here, Gordon.